# How to code a buffer in functional programming

Tags: c++, functional-programming, buffer

During the enforced break I decided to revisit a raytracer but for a difference I decided to do it with via functional programming rather than imperative.

However I have an issue: How do you have an offscreen buffer?

I have a `colour` class and the buffer would be an array of `colour` objects, but if a `colour` object is immutable then you can't simply update the object with a new colour.

So I was thinking of an array of `shared_ptr`s but that is swapping into an immutable buffer.

So my final way is to make strips of 16 (maybe more, maybe less) `colour` objects and have a linked list between them and when the image is finalised then copy the buffers into the offscreen buffer and flip that.

Is this the best way of doing it or am I missing a trick here?

Comment: time to learn about the [M-word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29)...

Comment: I understand Maybe (aka std::optional) but I can't seem to make the leap from that to a large flat buffer?

Comment: You need to understand State, and then use one of its various incarnations/siblings like STArray.

Comment: Do you want to learn functional programming the hard way, or the easy way?  The easy way is to learn it with a *functional first* functional programming language:  [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) or [The Book of F#](https://nostarch.com/fsharp).  The hard way is to learn functional programming in C++, or C#, or Lisp, or Scala, or Rust, or JavaScript, or Swift.

Comment: I want to learn functional programming in an environment I am comfortable in.  I have dipped my toes into Haskell and F# in the past: I spend more time try to figure out what the language is doing than the concepts behind it.

Comment: Another way to look at it is: what can I bring to my day job once lockdown ends? The first X pages of a book on Haskell or learning new concepts in a language I get paid to use?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about your domain of graphics buffers, but you might be searching for a [persistent data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure#Persistent_hash_array_mapped_trie): a data structure that provides you with efficient immutable updating better than copy-on-write.

Clojure has, IMHO, one of the best implementations of immutable vectors and dictionaries in its standard library, based on [array mapped tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_array_mapped_trie).  See [here](https://hypirion.com/musings/understanding-persistent-vector-pt-1) for an in-depth explaination and possible optimizations.

Additionally, there's a technique called *transients*, which allow you to give up immutability locally for effient builders, and can then be freezed in to an immutable structure before sharing the result.  This sounds a bit like your idea.

Know, though, that implementing stateful applications with large immutable data structures should not be an end in itself, unless you want to remain pure for a concrete reason.  It's great when you pass things around between actor-like components without having to worry about referential transparency or thread-safety, but maybe less so for essentially an updating loop over a buffer. (That's just a reply to your " what can I bring to my day job" comment.)